# How to put flash message into my code?

Tags: node.js, express, connect-flash

I have a function

```
function fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
        if (file.mimetype !== 'image/png' && file.mimetype !== 'image/jpg' && file.mimetype !== 'image/gif' ) {
            console.log('Wrong format!');
            return cb(null, false);
        }
        if ( file.size > 10000 ){
            console.log('Image is too big!');
            return cb(null, false);
        }
        cb(null, true);
}
var upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter });
```

This function works when I am making post request.

```
router.post('/changeAvatar', upload.single('avatar'), function(req, res) {
    var id = req.user._id;
    res.redirect('/user/'+id);
});
```

How can I put flash (`connect-flash`) instead off my console.log's?

`Connect-flash` is already installed, with `cookies` and `sessions`. I tried different ways, but I can't understand philosophy of flash messages...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first in your entry script you should use the connect flash middleware:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(session({cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));
app.use(flash());
```

then your function should look like :

```
  function fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
        if (file.mimetype !== 'image/png' && file.mimetype !== 'image/jpg' && file.mimetype !== 'image/gif' ) {
            req.flash('error', 'Wrong format!');
            return cb(null, false);
        }
        if ( file.size > 10000 ){
            req.flash('error', 'Image is too big!');
            return cb(null, false);
        }
        cb(null, true);
}
```

finally in  '/user/'+id  view you can get data from flash with :

```
JSON.stringify(req.flash('error'));
```